# how to build game puzzle 3 * 3?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, awt

Currently i am building game puzzle sliding using java. First My algorithm is create button array 2d with set image on those button and add them to panel(with grid layout 3*3). my problem is how can I compare each piece of image on those button  with original image? 
       Code below where i add button to Jpanel.

```
private void set() throws Exception {
    position = new int[row][col];
    lstBtn = new JButton[row][col];
    count = new int[row * col];
    arr=new ArrayList<>(9);

    panelContainer.setLayout(null);
    panelContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
    BufferedImage img;
    int numCount = 0;
    int posNum=0; 

    orgImg=new BufferedImage[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

           position[i][j] = posNum++;

            if (i ==0 & j == 0) {
           // For blank Button
                lstBtn[i][j] = new JButton();
                lstBtn[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
               // panelContainer.add(lstBtn[i][j]);
                lstBtn[i][j].setVisible(true);
                arr.add(lstBtn[i][j]);
                count[0] = numCount;
            }
            else {
                   numCount++;
                lstBtn[i][j] = new JButton();
                lstBtn[i][j].addActionListener(this);
             img = image_cutting.getSubImage(j,i);//160, 116 //120, 87,
             orgImg[j][i]=img;
              lstBtn[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(orgImg[j][i].getScaledInstance(160, 116, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                lstBtn[i][j].setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                lstBtn[i][j].setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                lstBtn[i][j].setFont(new Font("Dialog",2,20));
                lstBtn[i][j].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                 lstBtn[i][j].setText("" + numCount); 
                arr.add(lstBtn[i][j]);
             //  panelContainer.add(lstBtn[i][j]);
               lstBtn[i][j].setVisible(true);
            }
            if (numCount == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            count[numCount] = numCount;
        }
```

This image bellow is sample of puzzle sliding with match image

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more help

Comment: Don't compare the *images*.  Look at where the *buttons* are - each button has a "correct" position regardless of what image is on it.

Comment: yes this is what i want to find that, what should i do the way to know  button position is on the right place?

Comment: You need a model of some kind which keeps track of each image or piece, the UI then replicates the state of the model

Comment: yes i use array to store original image. but my problem is how to know it is correction position

Comment: The you need to devise a class which states it's correct position and it's image, which you can then compare to it's actual position

Comment: can you give sample?

Answer (score 1):

This is a conceptual idea, which will need some fleshing out, but.  Start with an idea of a single piece, which holds it's "order" or "index" within the puzzle and it's image

```
public class PuzzelPiece {
    private int index;
    private Image img;

    public PuzzelPiece(int index, Image img) {
        this.index = index;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return img;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }


}
```

Next, wrap this in some kind of model.  It should manage the pieces, provide access to them and possibly provide a "is ordered" check to determine if the pieces are in order.

This example takes a source image, the number of cols/rows you want and slice and dices the image into pieces.  It then shuffles the pieces and adds a blank piece in place of the first piece (the piece with the index of `0`)

```
public class Puzzle {

    private List<PuzzelPiece> pieces;

    public Puzzle(BufferedImage source, int cols, int rows) {

        int rowHeight = source.getHeight() / rows;
        int colWidth = source.getWidth() / cols;

        pieces = new ArrayList<>(25);
        int index = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                Image img = source.getSubimage(col * colWidth, row * rowHeight, colWidth, rowHeight);
                pieces.add(new PuzzelPiece(index++, img));
            }
        }
        pieces.remove(0);
        Collections.shuffle(pieces);
        pieces.add(new PuzzelPiece(0, null)); // Blank
    }

    public boolean isOrdered() {
        // Instead of sorting the list like this each time
        // you could just maintain two lists to start with
        // one ordered and one shuffled
        List<PuzzelPiece> ordered = new ArrayList<>(pieces);
        Collections.sort(ordered, new Comparator<PuzzelPiece>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(PuzzelPiece o1, PuzzelPiece o2) {
                return o1.getIndex() - o2.getIndex();
            }
        });
        boolean isOrdered = true;
        for (int index = 0; index < ordered.size(); index++) {
            if (ordered.get(index) != pieces.get(index)) {
                isOrdered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isOrdered;
    }

    public int size() {
        return pieces.size();
    }

    public PuzzelPiece getPieceAt(int index) {
        return pieces.get(index);
    }

    public void swap(PuzzelPiece piece, PuzzelPiece with) {
        int pieceIndex = pieces.indexOf(piece);
        int withIndex = pieces.indexOf(with);

        pieces.set(pieceIndex, with);
        pieces.set(withIndex, piece);
    }
}
```

It provides a simple `swap` method to swap pieces and simple `isOrdered` method to check to see if the list is ordered

This is untested and comes "as is" and is meant to drive the idea, to provide an implementation

Comment: `Puzzle#getPieceAt` which returns a `PuzzlePiece`, which you can then use `getImage`

Comment: According to your code if i set image to button. is it possible to know image is order on button?

Comment: Not via the buttons, but via the model. The idea is, when you want to swap the images, you do it via the model (which could have more logic in it to determine if the switch is legal or not) and then you'd update the buttons based on the state of the model. The intention is, your view should be dumb as possible, only reacting to the state of the model

Comment: so picture on button is only representative of image.

Comment: Pretty much, which image it displays is dependent on the model